# QTabWidget strange behaviour on mouse click

Tags: c++, qt, tabs

I am having a very erratic behaviour with QTabWidget interacting with the mouse.
It is a mainwindow that uses a QTabWidget as central widget and the tabs are created dynamically.

Here the constructor of the mainwindow:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent)
{
  this->mainTab = new QTabWidget;
  this->mainTab->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("MainTab"));
  this->mainTab->setMovable(true);
  this->mainTab->setTabsClosable(true);

  this->setCentralWidget(this->mainTab);
}
```

And the function that adds the tab:

```
void newTab(QString name)
{
  QString id = randomid;
  WidgetMapManager * newmanager = new WidgetMapManager(id, name);

  this->mainTab->addTab(newmanager,name);
  this->mainTab->setCurrentIndex(this->mainTab->count()-1);
}
```

The behaviour is rather difficult to explain. It is like if the rect that receives the click event in the tabs is out of place. Initially looked like if they were not receiving the click at all but, after much testing, it seems like some tabs can by clicked in some small section of the tab to the right, others cannot be clicked at all and the last one can always be clicked.

As you can see by the code, the tabs can be moved; well, as it is, only the last tab can be moved and the new tab becoming the last tab can then be selected and moved. As if the clickable rect was being shifted to right each time a tab is added and the tabs of the left are just totally out of them.

The widget that is being placed in the tab does not make a difference; I have tried with different ones. Have also tried making the tabs not moveable and not closable…

I am writing the application in QT Creator with QT 5.5 and MSVC 12 compiler for 32 bits.
Any light on this is much appreciated as I am running out of ideas.

Comment: Did you override `onMouseXX` of `WidgetMapManager`?

Comment: No. However, the widget is hosting some other widgets that have `setDragEnabled` to true and `setDragDropMode` to DragOnly. And hosting also another widget, which is receiving the drops and is overriding `dragEnterEvent` and `dropEvent`. I am not explicitly implementing the onMouse event in the widget that is used for the tab.